# MSBuild fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file

Tags: msbuild

I know there are others subjects on this, but none of their solutions worked for me.
I have this simple code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AccurateTimeStamping.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to build it using MSBuild. The following header is in another directory

```
AccurateTimeStamping.h
```

I already successfully build this project using MSBuild and environnement variable. But I want to avoid env variable. In command line I did this :

```
D:\propTest>msbuild.exe propTest.sln /p:ReferencePath=M:\Utils\include
```

Or this

```
D:\propTest>msbuild.exe propTest.sln /p:AdditionalIncludeDirectories=M:\Utils\include
```

Or This

```
D:\propTest>msbuild.exe propTest.sln /p:"ReferencePath=<M:\Utils\include>"
```

Or this :

```
D:\propTest>msbuild.exe propTest.sln /p:includepath=M:\Utils\include
```

But I still have :

```
d:\proptest\proptest\proptest.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
file: 'AccurateTimeStamping.h': No such file or directory
```

I can not modify the projects that I have to build and I can't change    .vcxproj.

Is there a way to pass the path of .h files to MSBuild using only command line and no env var??

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Running into the exact same issue using VS2013. The only solutions found online involve setting the path variables and altering a file. However I am trying to write a testing script which builds multiple projects.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb6c8578-c49a-480d-ba72-f95311bfd965/solution-can-build-in-vs2008-but-not-with-msbuild-due-to-c1083?forum=msbuild